# Is it possible to set Dash to show a black background instead of generated from the wallpaper?

Tags: themes, unity-dash

I prefer Natty's "black" dash background as opposed to the color-adopting background found in Oneiric.

Will Oneiric have a setting to change the default color and allow the dash to have a black background? Or can this not be changed?

Answer (score 2):

So far I have not found an option for this. You are welcome to report a bug on launchpad (just run `ubuntu-bug unity`) or bring this up on the Ayatana mailing list.